# Exception connecting to SQL Server CE 4.0

Tags: crt, sql-server-ce-4

When trying connecting to SQL Server CE 4.0 (`SqlServerCe.dll, v2.0.50727`), I get an exception (`System.Data.Common.DbException`) saying:

> *The CRT binary present in application/bin folder is not signed and
> can be a potential security risk. Please place the original Microsoft
> CRT binary in application/bin folder.*

All files are downloaded from microsoft.com

```
string localDataFile = Path.Combine(dataPath, "StorageData.sdf");
var connectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0}", localDataFile);

if (!File.Exists(localDataFile))
{
    SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
    engine.CreateDatabase();
    engine.Dispose();
}

var connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString); <----Here the exception occures
StorageContext context = new StorageContext(connection);

return context;
```

System:

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2010
- .NET 4.0

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Reinstalling the following files has fixed the problem:

- [SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709)
- [SSCEVSTools-ENU.msi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/aa983341.aspx)

Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: What does the connection string look like?? Can you inspect that in the debugger on that line, before the exception happens?

Comment: Are you using private deployment?

Comment: The connection string looks like: Data Source=\\172.32.234.51\Files\Archive_CentralStorage\ARC_Storage01\_Info\StorageData.sdf

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error today while helping one of our customers with a problem in our software:

> The CRT binary present in application/bin folder is not signed and can
>   be a potential security risk. Please place the original Microsoft CRT
>   binary in application/bin folder.

Our software was trying to create and initialize a Windows CE database.  I bypassed the issue by setting the following registry key described by [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2715304):

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing

I looked for the value "State".  It did not exist, so I created a DWORD value and set it to 23e00.  This corresponds to the Internet Options / Advanced setting "Check for publisher’s certificate Revocation" being unchecked (see the linked KB article above).

This may not be the best solution for you or other readers, but I wanted to record it for future reference.